# std::array of function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers, stdarray

I want to store function pointers inside `std::array` but after trying different approaches, I still cant even compile my program.

Here is version that doens't throw errors until I compile it.

```
namespace logic {
    class Chance : public Field {
        std::array<void(logic::Chance::*)(), 18> m_redChances;
    public:
        Chance(ChanceType type);
        void redChance1();
        void redChance2();
        ...
        void redChance18();
    };
}

logic::Chance::Chance(ChanceType type) 
    : Field(false), m_type(type) 
{
    m_redChances[0] = redChance1;
    m_redChances[1] = redChance2;
    ....
    m_redChances[17] = redChance18;
}
```

It gives me

> non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Tried to do something like this then

```
m_redChances[0] = &redChance1;
```

Ended with

> '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression

Tried to declare my array like this

```
std::array<void(*)(), 18> m_redChances;
```

> a value of type "void(logic::Chance::*)()" cannot be assigned to entity of type "void(*)()"

Edit:
So after implementing it like this:
`m_redChances[0] = &Chance::redChance1;` it works. How can I actually call this function (if that matters, I'm calling it from another member function).

I'v tried all kinds of stuff like:

```
void logic::Chance::activate(logic::Player& player){
    m_redChances[0];
    *m_redChances[0];       
    m_redChances[0]();
    (*m_redChances[0])();
}
```

Only the first line isnt underscored and marked as error before I even compile, yet it doesnt call my function. How can I achieve that then?

Comment: try with `m_redChances[0] = &Chance::redChance1;`

Comment: Unlike non-member functions, member functions don't covert to member function pointers automatically. Hence, you need to use `&Chance::redChance1`, `&Chance::redChance2`, etc.

Comment: You are not trying to store (free) function pointers in your array. You are trying to store pointers to *member* functions - which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: If you search for that error message in SO, you get lots of posts. https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a434551%20member%20function%20pointer.

Comment: First the function pointer looks like this void (*foo)(int), where foo is the name of the function pointer and int is the parameter type. Second you could also try with std::function<void(int)> = std::bind(&Object:Function, Arg...). Please refer to the link http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind